# python 3.7.5: asyncio.get_event_loop did not create event loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

My main python thread does not use `asyncio`, but it creates a new thread whose code uses `asyncio`, where it encountered an error when calling `get_event_loop()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/hanxu/work/thunderrock/node_server/quic/udp_async.py", line 33, in udp_async
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-5'.
```

Per online document of [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop), `get_event_loop` should automatically create a new event loop if no existing yet. Why does it fail in this case?  Is it because of threading?

Btw I am doing the following to workaround, but still wondering why the issue existed:

```
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

Comment: maybe python3.7 still has behaviour  as python 3.6 which is strange or maybe you use python 3.6
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop

Comment: Are you sure there is no code that uses asyncio internally, perhaps as part of a framework? The docs do say "if [...] `set_event_loop()` has not yet been called". It is enough for someone to invoke `asyncio.run(...)` for this feature to break.

Comment: @user4815162342 there is a framework using asyncio (namely `aioquic`) but it shouldn't set the event loop to none.  Btw,  when I ran the same code as a separate process (instead of thread), the issue is gone.  I was wondering if that `asyncio` only creates the event loop automatically for the main thread, but I cannot pinpoint to its source code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the question.

The documentation is slightly incorrect, new even loop is implicitly created only for the main thread.

Please track https://bugs.python.org/issue39381 for the fix.